# When i use VoiceOver of Mac to navigate through the website, focus is remaining at a button and its being there until another button is encountered

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, accessibility

When I use VoiceOver of Mac to navigate the website using the keyboard command (cmd+shift+left/right arrows), the focus remains on a button. It is there until another button is encountered. The issue is only in Chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers. The above-mentioned scenario is working well for Safari and Firefox browsers. When a button gets the focus and VoiceOver moves to other text elements, due to the focus of the button, the voiceover is again navigating back to the focused button and iterating through the elements that are already read.

I tried "focusin","focusout" event listeners to set aria-hidden / tabIndex values accordingly. I also tried setting the focus of elements using CSS, making box-shadow:none, outline:none, but that just makes the focus not visible.

Comment: try `:focus-visible{outline:none}` this css property. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks @Aslamkhan, but after applying this, if I navigate using the keyboard key "Tab" for Chrome, the interactive button is not getting highlighted.

Comment: you can use particular border or outline on `:focus` event.

Comment: enabling ":focus" brings back the previous issue, which is the focus being stuck at the button, even though the screen reader navigates to other non-interactive elements. It needs to work both ways one with tabbing via keyboard, and two navigating through the page with Voiceover. I think this could also be a Chrome browser issue, please correct me if I am wrong.